# Heroku app produces an application error ("critical worker timeout") while celery background task produces a successful result, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, redis, celery

I have an app hosted on Heroku that uses a flask/celery api that runs a genetic algorithm, my heroku app produces an application error (critical worker timeout) while the celery background task still runs and produces a successful result. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the heroku log (link because its long): https://hastebin.com/ifakexilep.vbs

and here is my app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from celery import Celery
from json import dumps
import json
import os
import pandas as pd
from redis import Redis
import full_ga

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = os.environ.get('REDISCLOUD_URL')
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = os.environ.get('REDISCLOUD_URL')

#celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
#celery.conf.update(app.config)

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

celery = make_celery(app)
api = Api(app)

def jsonify(data):
    json_data = dict()
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, list): # for lists
            value = [ jsonify(item) if isinstance(item, dict) else item for 
item in value ]
        if isinstance(value, dict): # for nested lists
            value = jsonify(value)
        if isinstance(key, int): # if key is integer: > to string
            key = str(key)
        if type(value).__module__=='numpy': # if value is numpy.*: > to 
python list
            value = value.tolist()
        json_data[key] = value
    return json_data

@celery.task(name='__main__.generate_plan')
def generate_plan(experience_level, plan_length_in_months, 
num_workouts_per_week):
    w = full_ga.full_ga(experience_level, plan_length_in_months, 
num_workouts_per_week)
    p = w.plan_ga()
    #sleep(1000)
    return jsonify(p)

class create_workout_plan(Resource):

    def get(self, experience_level, plan_length_in_months, 
num_workouts_per_week):

        plan = generate_plan.delay(experience_level, plan_length_in_months, 
num_workouts_per_week)

        return plan.get()

    api.add_resource(create_workout_plan, 
    '/<experience_level>/<plan_length_in_months>/<num_workouts_per_week>') 

    if __name__ == '__main__':
         app.run()
```

Any help/tips on what may be going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `app.run()` call, by default, binds to 127.0.0.1 (localhost), port 5000. Heroku expects your app to bind to 1) an externally visible address via 2) the port it passes to your application (via the `PORT` environment variable). If your app does not bind within 30 seconds, Heroku flags the app as crashed.

Change it to:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=os.environ.get('PORT', '5000'))
```

You will of course need to add `import os` to the preamble of your script.

Hope that helps.